# php password validation is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a registration form with confirm password but my password confirmation is not working. I want Password mismatch validation here.

Where have I made mistake? Please help me to fix this.

## PHP Validation Script

```
<?php

$user=$country=$state=$city=$account=$email=$password="";
$userErr=$countryErr=$stateErr=$cityErr=$accountErr=$emailErr=$passwordErr="";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
  $valid = true;

    if(empty($_POST["username"]))
    {
        $userErr="* Username is Required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $user=test_input($_POST["username"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["country"]))
    {
        $countryErr="* Country is required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $country=test_input($_POST["country"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["state"]))
    {
        $stateErr="* State is required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $state=test_input($_POST["state"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["city"]))
    {
        $cityErr="* City is required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $city=test_input($_POST["city"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["accounttype"]))
    {
    $accountErr="*AccountType is required";
    $valid=false;   
    }
    else
    {
        $account=test_input($_POST["accounttype"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $emailErr="* Email is required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $email=test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }
    if($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"])
    {
        $passwordErr="* Password does not match";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $password=test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;

}

?>
```

## This is my form

```
 <form action="join_form1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <tr>
      <td width="163"><div align="right">User Name:</div></td>
      <td width="409"><input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo $user?>" /><?php echo $userErr?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Country:</div></td>
      <td><select name="country">
      <option value="<?php echo $country ?>"><?php echo "$country"; ?></option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select><?php echo $countryErr?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">State: </div></td>
      <td><input name="state" type="text" value="<?php echo $state ?>" /><?php echo $stateErr?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">City: </div></td>
      <td>
        <input name="city" type="text" value="<?php echo "$city"; ?>" /><?php echo $cityErr?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Account Type: </div></td>
      <td><select name="accounttype">
        <option value="<?php echo $account ?>"></option>
        <option value="a">Normal User</option>
        <option value="b">Expert User</option>
        <option value="c">Super User</option>
      </select><?php echo $accountErr?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Email: </div></td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email ?>" /><?php echo $emailErr?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Password: </div></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" /><?php echo $passwordErr?><br /> 
      <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces no symbols)</font></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Confirm Password: </div></td>
      <td><input name="confirm_password" type="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" /><?php echo $passwordErr?><br /> 
      <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces no symbols)</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Captcha: </div></td>
      <td>Add Captcha Here for security</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
```

Comment: You have: `if($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"]) $passwordErr="* Password does not match";`, should be `!==`

Comment: As @billionecan said, this should be if($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirm_password"]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in your code if password and confirm password match then error is Password does not match"; 


if($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"])
    {
        $passwordErr="* Password does not match";
        $valid=false;
    }
replace it

if($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirm_password"])
{
        $passwordErr="* Password does not match";
        $valid=false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
if($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirm_password"])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check like this

```
if($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirm_password"])
    {
        $passwordErr="* Password does not match";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $password=test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }
```